# How to update an HTML object when attribute is removed

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

The purpose of the code is to evaluate an item from the localStorage and if it is defined, makes a `<p></p>` visible. But when it enters to `if(error)` the `hidden` attribute is removed but the `<p></p>` doesn't update. To see it I have to manually refresh the page. What can I do to solve this?

Here is the javascript code:

```
const renderApp = () =>{
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    const role = localStorage.getItem('role')
    const error = localStorage.getItem('error')
    const parrafo = document.getElementById('error')
    if (token) {
            if (role=== 'user') {
                location.href = "pacientes.html"

            }else if( role === 'medico'){
                location.href = "medico.html"
            }
        }
    if (error) {
        parrafo.removeAttribute("hidden")
    }
}


window.onload= () => {
    renderApp()
    const loginForm= document.getElementById('login')
    loginForm.onsubmit = (e) =>{    
        e.preventDefault()
        const cedula = document.getElementById('cedula').value
        const password = document.getElementById('password').value

        fetch('https://janfa.gharsnull.now.sh/api/auth/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({cedula, password})
        }).then( x => x.json())
          .then( respuesta => {
            localStorage.setItem('token' , respuesta.token)
            localStorage.setItem('error', respuesta.error)
            return respuesta.token
          })
          .then( token=> {
            return fetch('https://janfa.gharsnull.now.sh/api/auth/me', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    authorization : token,
                },
            })
          })
          .then( x => x.json())
          .then ( user => {
            localStorage.setItem('role', user['role'])
            renderApp()
          })
    }
}
```

The function `renderApp()` is called when the page loads and when the form is submitted

EDIT: uhmm i'm gonna add a stack snippet because I was told to but i dont really know how to use it, hope everything goes well

```js
let ruta = 'login'

const renderApp = () =>{
 const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
 const role = localStorage.getItem('role')
 const error = localStorage.getItem('error')
 const parrafo = document.getElementById('error')
 if (token) {
   if (role=== 'user') {
    location.href = "pacientes.html"

   }else if( role === 'medico'){
    location.href = "medico.html"
   }
  }
 if (error) {
  parrafo.removeAttribute("hidden")
 }
}


window.onload= () => {
 renderApp()
 const loginForm= document.getElementById('login')
 loginForm.onsubmit = (e) =>{ 
  e.preventDefault()
  const cedula = document.getElementById('cedula').value
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value

  fetch('https://janfa.gharsnull.now.sh/api/auth/login', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({cedula, password})
  }).then( x => x.json())
    .then( respuesta => {
     localStorage.setItem('token' , respuesta.token)
     localStorage.setItem('error', respuesta.error)
     return respuesta.token
    })
    .then( token=> {
     return fetch('https://janfa.gharsnull.now.sh/api/auth/me', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       authorization : token,
      },
     })
    })
    .then( x => x.json())
    .then ( user => {
     localStorage.setItem('role', user['role'])
     renderApp()
    })
 }

}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans&display=swap');

body{
 background-color: #eee;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.container-form{
 background-color: white;
 justify-content: center;
 border-radius: 10px;
 width: 80%;
 max-width: 500px;
 max-height: 350px;
 padding: 20px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

label{
 display: block;
 width: 500px;
 margin-left: 0;
}

input{
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.login input{
 border-radius: 5px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(42,171,238,0.5);
}

input[type="submit"]{
 border: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: #2AABEE;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 40px;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans', cursive; 
}

input[type="text"],input[type="password"] {
 padding-left: 10px;
 
}

::placeholder{
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

h2, label{
 font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans', cursive;
}

h2{
 color: #2AABEE;
}

label{
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.container-form a{
 color: #2AABEE;
}

#error{
 color: tomato;
 font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Janfa-Login</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Login.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-form">
  <form class="login" id="login">
   <h2>Log in</h2>
   <label>Documento de identidad</label>
   <p id="error" hidden>Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos</p>
   <input type="text" id="cedula" placeholder="Documento de identidad">
   <label>Contraseña</label>
   <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
   <input type="submit" name="">
   
   <a href="#">Olvidé mi contraseña</a>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add that logic to remove the hidden attribute inside `loginForm.onsubmit` as well.

Currently you don't have validation logic in onsubmit, therefore submitting a completed form will still send error to localStorage. Here's a barebones validation example where it checks if the inputs are at least three characters or more and if it fails, the error tag hidden property is removed.

```js
loginForm.onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const cedula = document.getElementById("cedula").value;
  const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  // if empty or too short
  if (cedula.trim().length < 3 || password.trim().length < 3) {
    parrafo.removeAttribute("hidden")
  }

...
```

Comment: nope, the <p> has id="error", as I said, The attribute hidden does disappear but to see the changes I have to refresh the page

Comment: could you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), by using codepen or [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)? This would help us solve the issue.

Comment: wait but doesn't the renderApp() inside the `loginForm.onsubmit` does the same? just in a different function

Comment: wtf bro? I just tested it and it works. I don't understand whats wrong with my code

Comment: placing `renderApp()` inside submit does achieve the same result, but since `renderApp()` does other logic, such using role or token, when all you really needed is to remove an attribute, is not a good design.

Comment: if my solution solved the issue, it would be awesome if you could upvote it or select the checkmark :)

Comment: hmm yeah sorry, you did help me. I was just trying to process whats going on. Thank you!!